# Finding/Setting the first day of the week

Tags: settings, calendars

I am using a time tracking app that can report time spent on various categories in a day, week, month and so on. The developer tells me that the "Week" code uses a phone setting for the first day of the week and does not have its own setting exposed for that. I think that's fine.

On Windows Phone 7.x, under Region and Language settings you can see First Day of the Week along with date format and many other settings. On Windows Phone 8, there are Language and Region settings but far fewer, and first day of the week is not there. It is also not under Date and Time.

Even if I can't change this setting, how can I find out what it is? I don't know if my time totals are Monday through Sunday or Sunday through Saturday, or what. I don't really feel like hand adding them up to test for myself - the phone surely must be able to tell me this, mustn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *first day of the week* setting isn't in Windows Phone 8 anymore (Why, I don't know...). It's on the users' feature suggestions in the WP website, [here](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3719160-first-day-of-the-week-setting).

It seems that on WP8 the first day is automatically set, depending on the Country/Region set in *Language and Region*.

To know which is the first day of the week on your phone, open the *Calendar* and choose the *Month* view, you'll find it as it's the first from the left.

Comment: I'm annoyed now, because I can see from the Calendar that it's Sunday, and I have no idea how to make it Monday. But I appreciate the pointer for how to find out what it is, and confirmation that I can't change it. I've also voted for the feature suggestion and hope others do too.

Answer (score -3):

From G_L_ on http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/windows-8-calendar-set-start-of-week-to-sunday/a8deca2b-7b9d-4625-aefa-9ea2ad956e29?msgId=58a6c884-92e9-4130-8d21-f4fdfb75a79a

Actually you can set the first day of the week.  But it's not immediately obvious.

1) Open the calander from the taskbar and select "Change Date and Time"
 2) Select "Change date and time..."  (yes again)
 3) Select "Change calendar settings"
 4) There it is - down the bottom

OR

1) Open Control Panel
 2) Open "Region"
 3) It's right there, too

Comment: This looks to be an answer on how to do this on Windows 8, not the phone.